# Email Column auto populated from Created By?

Tags: 2010

SharePoint 2010.  I have a document library and I'd like to have an Email column that automatically fills in from active directory based on the Created By column. Is there a way to do this?  Or to have the Created By column display an email address instead?

Answer (score 1):

I try not to duplicate data whenever possible, so going into the library's settings you can click on the Created By column and change the display option to Work Email instead of Name and show the email address.